# How do I remove the margins for li's in an ul?

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list with a bunch of li's. But I can't seem to remove the margins between li's.

Here's what I would like it to look like:

[image]

And this is what it looks like now:

[image]

What could I try next?

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/narzero/76egxmt9/

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="content_panel active">
    <ul class="unstyled items_board">
      <li class="item_header">First</li>
      <li class="has_details item">one</li>
      <li class="has_details item">two</li>
      <li class="has_details item">three</li>
      <li class="has_details item">four</li>
      <li class="has_details item">five</li>
      <li class="has_details item">six</li>

      <li class="item_header">Second</li>
      <li class="has_details item">one</li>
      <li class="has_details item">two</li>
      <li class="has_details item">three</li>
      <li class="has_details item">four</li>
      <li class="has_details item">five</li>
      <li class="has_details item">six</li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.content_panel .active {
  display: inherit;
}

.unstyled {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;

  /* border:1px solid #e5edec; */
}

ul {
  display: block;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

li {
  line-height: 20px;
}

ul > .unstyled {
  margin-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.items_board {
  padding: 4px;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.item_header {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 42px;
  cursor: auto;
  border: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.item_header:first-child {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.items_board .item {
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 -1px -1px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 205px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-weight: 400;
  border: 1px solid #e5edec;
}

.has_details {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: look http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/

Comment: just give a `float:left;` for your li.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `font-size: 0;` to `.unstyled` then add `font-size` (e.g. 16px) to `li` to remove the white space between inline-block elements like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wtcqgacx/)**

```
.unstyled {
    font-size: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    /* border:1px solid #e5edec; */
}
li {
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

**OR:** Add `float: left;` to `li` - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oLj0k3ro/)**

More Info:

> [Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) - by Chris Coyier

Answer (score 1):

Try to use  `float:left;` and not `display:inline-block;` at li items (`.items_board > .item` )
Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/r7v5pfzx/